# Upperbound on $E(AB)$ where $E(A)\le M < \infty$

Tags: probability, self-learning, upper-lower-bounds

Can we find upperbound on $E(AB)$, where $A,B$ are positive random variables with finite moments and $E(A)\le M < \infty$ using $E(B)$?
$$
E(AB)\le M E(B)
$$
or using some other constant, or how to deal with such problem, when you know upperbound on one expected value and try to do some upperbound of multiplication?

Comment: No, as $B$ can be negative.

Comment: see edited, sorry I forgot to mentioned, they are positive @gnu-supporter

Comment: Again no to the edited question.  Consider constant $A$ and $B$ be any positive random variables without finite mean.

Comment: But then inequality holds, since we use expectation of $B$ in upperbound

Comment: Yes, that's true, but you ask for upper bound of E(AB), which is unbounded in my example, so I answered no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A=B$ be any r.v. with finite first moment and with infinite second moment. For example, we can use random variales with [Pareto distribution with shape parameter $\alpha=2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution).

Then $\mathbb E(AB)=\mathbb E(A^2)=\infty$ but $\mathbb E(B)<\infty$ and the inequality fails.